# Show page from another URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

For, example, if I have this working link:

```
/test1/index.php?prop1=val1
```

And I have this HTML tag:

```
<a href="/test2-val2/">link</a>
```

How can I use this tag for opening the first link with the following content:

```
/new_link-test1/index.php?prop2=val2
```

My guess was to use `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^new_link-(.*)/$ /test1/index.php?$1 [L]
```

It works fine until I have the following next URL:

```
/new_link-(.*)/?other_params=other_values
```

with additional unusable parameters which show after page manipulations.

And when this URL opens, it doesn't show me the content on working link.

How can I change `.htaccess` to fix this?

Comment: I think you mean `<a href="/prop2-val2/">link</a>` instead of `<a href="/test2-val2/">link</a>`

Comment: Can your provide you exact .htaccess rule(s), 3 links, and what it should be rewriting to?

Comment: You can't write meaningful answers to regular expression questions without providing very clear examples of what val2 other_values etc actually look like. Since this is pattern matching, you have to show what the patterns actually look like. Then answering is easy.